# xamarin card view layout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to recreate a cardview similar to this one with an image with title on top and then some data and maybe some action buttons below. But for the life of me I can't get the text to be on top of the image.
 [image]

Here is what I have so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="325dp"
android:layout_margin="8dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recipeName"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="description"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recipeName"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="View"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recipeName"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean the layer of the textview? Can you give us screenshots from your app to get better impression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you want `@+id/recipeName` on top of `@+id/image1`.

On `recipeName`, you have set: `android:layout_below="@+id/image1"` which will layout the element *below* `image1`.  Remove that line as you do not want it below that element.  Try `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"`.  There are enough layout parameters to do most things: [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html), though it can be a bit of a rabbit hole once you start doing complex layouts...

Also you've got `layout_below` on elements inside your `LinearLayout` which won't do anything.

Comment: Yes trying to get recipe name on the bottom of the image. I will check out the various layout params you have mentioned.  Thanks man.